# How to stub new Worker()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, assert, sinon

I've wrote a function that create workers with a limitation and that create a queue of workers which will be created when a slot in the pool will be free.

here is the method

```js
export function getWorker(path: string): Promise<Worker> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (pool.length < limit) {
            const worker = new Worker(path)
            pool.push(worker)
            resolve(worker)
        } else {
            queue.push({
                resolve,
                path
            })
        }
    })
}
```

I want to test that this method do not create more workers than the limit.
I'm using SinonJS.

My question is: is there a way to stub `new Worker()` and have something in my test like `assert.callCount(myStub, limit)`?

Or maybe there is a better way to test how much worker have been created?

Answer (score -1):

You simply `sinon.stub(window, 'Worker')`.

Thanks to this, you can assert on `window.Worker.callCount` or any other sinon spy indicators. You may also want to define prototype for this new stub if you expect some tested code to call methods on those workers.

Remember about `window.Worker.restore` after test.

(Note, that `window.Worker` is defined only in browser env, in Node env you have to create fake `global.Worker` constructor and use `global` as "container" in `sinon.stub` call)

Comment: If you import Worker from `worker_threads` library and then try to do something like `global.Worker = Worker` you'll get a type error